# MySQL - Compare each field with the rest of the database

Tags: mysql, select, conditional-statements

i'm getting crazy trying to figure this out with pure MySQL and no PHP.

I want to select rows only if the comparition of that row with the rest of the database gives certain number which is not important.

The thing im trying to achieve is something like this:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE field > ( SELECT f FROM table WHERE date < XXX )

Comment: Not quite sure I understand.  But using a max(f) isn't what you're looking for, right?

Comment: Do you want to filter where `field` is more then **any** of the rows from the subquery? or more then **all** of them?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the query in brackets does not return a single value (because date < XXX indicates more values with respect to time). So...

I think what you need to try and do is form a relationship between table2 and table1 so that you can make a per-row field cell comparison.

E.g.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT f FROM table2 WHERE data < xxx) t2 
ON t1.foo = t2.bar
WHERE t1.field > t2.f
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you want is a combination of group, count, and having.  For exampleif you wanted to find all users who have made more than 10 posts since a certain date, you could do

```
SELECT *, COUNT(posts.id) as pcount 
from users 
left join posts on (posts.user = users.id AND post_made > ZZZ)  
HAVING COUNT(posts.id) > 10
```

The having clause lets you use aggregate fields like in a where clause.